# Pair key values that in same array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

This is my JSON data:

```
{
    "1": "apple",
    "2": "banana",
    "3": "orange"
     ...
}
```

I am trying to loop through and pair the values in the following way:

```
["apple","banana"] // [1,2]
["banana","orange"] // [2,3]
...
```

So far I have tried this. It loops thru 2 times and only gives me [1,2] pair result.

```
$k = 1;
for($i = 1; $i < count($jsonData); ++$i) {
            $pair = [$jsonData[$i], $jsonData[$k + 1]];
            $pairs += $pair;
            $k++;
        }
```

Result: `["apple","banana"]`

Note that array can be any size but cannot less or equal to 1.
How could I accomplish this in PHP?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `$pairs += $pair;` with `$pairs[] = $pair;`.

Because `+` for arrays just **skips** keys that are already in array. And these keys are `0` and `1` which appear after the first iteration of your `for` loop.

As @Nick stated - `$k` is redundant. So your code can be:

```
$pairs = [];
for($i = 1; $i < count($jsonData); ++$i) {
    $pair = [$jsonData[$i], $jsonData[$i + 1]];
    $pairs[] = $pair;
}
print_r($pairs);
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/G6qQi).

Comment: You might want to point out that `$k` is redundant since it exactly tracks `$i`

Comment: I thought this was the answer but after checking now it returns as `[["apple","banana"],["banana","banana"]]` 

Comment: Updated  the asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the same pair variable. You need to instead collect them. I would suggest to *not* depend on keys to be sequential when you rather just want pairing with values. You can maintain a `prev` variable to only have paired values of previous and current value.

```
<?php

$s = '{"1": "apple", "2": "banana", "3": "orange"}';
$jsonData = json_decode($s, true);

$pairs = [];
$prev = array_shift($jsonData); // pop the first element off as a previous value
foreach($jsonData as $key => $value){
    $pairs[] = [$prev , $value];
    $prev = $value;
}

print_r($pairs);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/Eeg7C

Answer (score 0):

1. `count()` should not be called over and over inside your loop because the value never changes.  Write it as part of the first argument of `for()`.
2. You can push the new data directly into the output array, there is no need to create a temporary/single-use variable (`$pair`).
3. Instead of adding 1 in the new array declarations and incrementing `$i` in the 3rd argument of `for()`, you can simply increment `$i` while declaring the new array data using `++$i` in the square braces.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XUa8o))

```
$array = json_decode('{"1": "apple", "2": "banana", "3": "orange"}', true);

for ($i = 1, $count = count($array); $i < $count;) {
    $pairs[] = [$array[$i], $array[++$i]];
}
var_export($pairs);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'apple',
    1 => 'banana',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'banana',
    1 => 'orange',
  ),
)
```